# Exception occured: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, Genre>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Genre>' stackTrace: #0 new GenreResponse.fromJson

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am getting Exception error in my flutter project, can someone help me on this

```
class GenreResponse {
  final List<Genre> genres;
  final String error;

  GenreResponse(this.genres, this.error);

  GenreResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : genres = (json["genres"] as List).map((e) => new Genre.fromJson(json)),
        error = "";

  GenreResponse.withError(String errorValue)
      : genres = List(),
        error = errorValue;
}
```

also, I am adding my genre.dart code here for better understanding

```
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Genre(this.id, this.name);

  Genre.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json["id"],
        name = json["name"];
}
```

Comment: Please share the output of printing the JSON map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.toList()` to your `.map()` line:

```
GenreResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : genres = (json["genres"] as List).map((e) => new Genre.fromJson(json)).toList(),
    error = "";
```

This just happens because the output of `.map()` is `MappedListIterable` and not a `List`. The annoying bit is that this isn't caught by the compiler, but I suppose is something to do with how the inheritance works.